# How do UPSERT with on conflict two or more constraints?

Tags: postgresql, upsert

I have a table:

[image]

I want insert or update data, that I get from another table. My constrains are three fields: id_1, id_2 and date. It's fields must be unique together.
If I do:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
ADD CONSTRAINT constr_1 UNIQUE (id_1, id_2, date);
```

and then:

```
insert into my_table
(id_1, id_2, quantity, date)
values (1, null, 5, '2022-04-27'),   -- values I get another select request
       (null, 5, 5, '2022-04-27'),  -- this means that the values can be different
       (99, 85, 100, '2022-04-29')
ON CONFLICT (id_1, id_2, date)
DO Update
SET quantity = excluded.quantity
```

Constrains not work and I just insert new rows with the same values. How to insert in the absence of a record and update in its presence?

Comment: Have you tried creating the constraint with `MATCH PARTIAL`. `ALTER TABLE my_table ADD CONSTRAINT constr_1 UNIQUE (id_1, id_2, date) MATCH PARTIAL`

Comment: Philippe, it`s not work:  ERROR:  syntax error at or near "MATCH"

Comment: @Philippe match partial refer to foreign key constraint. also  MATCH PARTIAL is not yet implemented. as per manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL treats NULL as distinct value, therefore, you can have multiple NULL values in a column with a UNIQUE index. When you define a primary key or a unique constraint for a table, PostgreSQL automatically creates a corresponding UNIQUE index.
The solution is to create a unique index, with coalesce. In this example I have used `coalesce(~, 0)` which means that null and 0 are treated as the same thing. You might prefer to use another value, for example the maximum possible value of int which is 2147483648.Please not that we have to modify the ON CONFLICT list to match the index.

> ```
> CREATE temp TABLE my_table (
>     id_1 int,
>     id_2 int,
>     quantity numeric,
>     mytable_date date
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE UNIQUE INDEX
> my_table_unique ON my_table
> (coalesce(id_1,0), coalesce(id_2,0), coalesce(mytable_date,'1900-01-01'));
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO my_table (id_1, id_2, quantity, mytable_date)
>     VALUES (1, NULL, 5, '2022-04-27'), (NULL, 5, 5, '2022-04-27'), (99, 85, 100, '2022-04-29')
> ON CONFLICT (coalesce(id_1,0), coalesce(id_2,0), coalesce(mytable_date,'1900-01-01'))
>     DO UPDATE SET
>         quantity = excluded.quantity;
>
> INSERT INTO my_table (id_1, id_2, quantity, mytable_date)
>     VALUES (99, 85, 101, '2022-04-29')
> ON CONFLICT (coalesce(id_1,0), coalesce(id_2,0), coalesce(mytable_date,'1900-01-01'))
>     DO UPDATE SET
>         quantity = excluded.quantity;
> ```

3 rows affected

> 

1 rows affected

> 

> ```
> select * from my_table;
> ```
>
> ```
> id_1 | id_2 | quantity | mytable_date
> ---: | ---: | -------: | :-----------
>    1 | null |        5 | 2022-04-27  
> null |    5 |        5 | 2022-04-27  
>   99 |   85 |      101 | 2022-04-29
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=4197c3ba1fa1b0607b19736c708126af)*74bf159a4d041c31fec5f)*

Comment: unfortunately, this does not fit, columns can be null and there can be the same values in the columns. There cannot be the same values together (id_1, date) and (id_2, date)

Comment: I've modified my answer. We can use coalesce in a unique index, which we cannot do in a unique constraint.

Comment: Thank, but at some point I get error: ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE command cannot affect row a second time

Comment: When you do an update it locks the row until the end of the transaction. If you try to update the same row twice in the same transaction the RDBMS is blocked and throws an error. If you are updating and entering several rows as long as there is no duplicate of the unique index in the values supplied in the same transaction. This is normal behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE temp TABLE my_table (
    id_1 int,
    id_2 int,
    quantity numeric,
    mytable_date date
);

ALTER TABLE my_table
    ADD CONSTRAINT constr_1 UNIQUE (id_1, id_2, mytable_date);
```

then

```
INSERT INTO my_table (id_1, id_2, quantity, mytable_date)
    VALUES (1, NULL, 5, '2022-04-27'), (NULL, 5, 5, '2022-04-27'), (99, 85, 100, '2022-04-29')
ON CONFLICT (id_1, id_2, mytable_date)
    DO UPDATE SET
        quantity = excluded.quantity;

INSERT INTO my_table (id_1, id_2, quantity, mytable_date)
    VALUES (99, 85, 101, '2022-04-29')
ON CONFLICT (id_1, id_2, mytable_date)
    DO UPDATE SET
        quantity = excluded.quantity;
```

please check manual section: **5.4.3. Unique Constraints** about special case: **null**.

> In general, a unique constraint is violated if there is more than one
> row in the table where the values of all of the columns included in
> the constraint are equal. However, **two null values are never
> considered equal in this comparison.** That means even in the presence
> of a unique constraint it is possible to store duplicate rows that
> contain a null value in at least one of the constrained columns. This
> behavior conforms to the SQL standard, but we have heard that other
> SQL databases might not follow this rule. So be careful when
> developing applications that are intended to be portable.

Comment: It`s not work. this does not fit, columns can be null and there can be the same values in the columns. There cannot be the same values together (id_1, date) and (id_2, date)

Comment: (1,1,'2020-01-01')  does not the same as (1,1,'2020-01-02')  !

Comment: Yes, i need that: this line (1,1,'2020-01-01') update this (null,1,'2020-01-01') and insert new this (10,1,'2020-01-02'). And this line (1,null,'2020-01-01) update this (1,1,'2020-01-01) and insert this (1,10,'2020-01-02)